# How to enable horizontal drag-drop in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I am using VS 2013 Professional. I am trying to make a website in ASP.net Web forms (C#). While using the web designer in visual studio, I cannot drag and drop elements vertically. In other words, no matter where I drop the element, it appears at the start of the line. I've done research and this appears to be a common problem. However, still no solution found. How do I enable FULL drag and drop control, not just vertically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move Controls freely in VS 2013 by:

1. Remove all current controls
2. Go to Tools > Options > Html Designer > CSS Styling > Change positioning to absolute for controls added using Toolbox, paste or drag and drop.
3. Now drag and drop a new control in page.

*** 4. Click on the Label that appear above the control (asp:button#Button1 for instance) and move it any where you want.

**A friendly piece of advice:**

But it seems that you aren't familiar with web designing, this way is not recommended, it's not a WindowsForm, you deal with wide rang of browsers and resolutions.
In fact when you can move controls freely, you set `style="position: absolute"`.

When your web page is finished, then open it and resize your browser, then you will completely understand what I'm saying.
If you want to design a real web page, you should go for `CSS` and do a little search about it.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, this was a great help

Comment: Thanks for ur advice. I actually know css and html already, I am just new to the concept of asp.net and was thinking of using a different way. That is until I saw ur answer. Maybe a grid layout like Bootstrap would be better then ?

Comment: Absolutely, you can create your own layout or use something like `Bootstrap` as you say. Don't use this drag solution in a real project.